# Extracting a sub data frame from original data frame by specifying the multi index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First, I made a following data frame which has two indeices `file_id` and `obj_id` so the left two data are not columns.

```
file_id    obj_id    val_1    val_2 ...
'file_1'   0         111      222
           2         111      222
           4         413      1231
'file_2'   5         111      222
           27        111      222
           3         413      1231       
           9         413      1231 
'file_3'   0         111      222
           2         111      222
           4         413      1231
...
```

I want to extract multiple rows specified by `file_id` and create a new data frame maintaining the original structure. For example, if I have a list `['file_1', 'file_3']`, the desired output is

```
file_id    obj_id    val_1    val_2 ...
'file_1'   0         111      222
           2         111      222
           4         413      1231
'file_3'   0         111      222
           2         111      222
           4         413      1231
```

I firstly tried to drop all unnecessary rows but it requires specifying the second index `obj_id` so

```
df.drop(['file_2', 'file_4', 'file_5' ...]) # Throw exception
df.drop(('file_2', 5)) # Works but leave other rows in file_2, I need to drop all row in file_2

file_id    obj_id    val_1    val_2 ...
'file_2'   27        111      222
           3         413      1231
           9         413      1231 
...
```

As `obj_id` depends on each `file_id`, this dropping method does not work unless there is something like wild card. Also dropping requires many steps, I wish I could simply extract rows by list of `file_id`. Is there any solution?

Comment: Since `file` is the outer-most level of your `MultiIndex` you should just need to use `.loc`: `df.loc[["file_1", "file_2"], :]`

Comment: It works as I wanted! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my comment as an answer so OP can mark this as answered:

Since file is the outer-most level of your `MultiIndex you should just need to use` .loc`:

```
df.loc[["file_1", "file_2"], :]
```